# Omniture Data Warehouse API Not Allowing 'hour' Value for Date_Granularity

Tags: api, rest, data-warehouse, adobe-analytics

When using the Omniture Data Warehouse API Explorer ( https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/get-started/api-explorer#DataWarehouse.Request ), the following request provides an 'Date_Granularity is invalid response'.  Does anyone have experience with this?  The API documentation ( https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation/data-warehouse/pdf ), states that the following values are acceptable: "none, hour, day, week, month, quarter, year."

```
{
"Breakdown_List":[
    "evar14",
    "ip",
    "evar64",
    "evar65",
    "prop63",
    "evar6",
    "evar16"
],
"Contact_Name":"[hidden]",
"Contact_Phone":"[hidden]",
"Date_From":"12/01/11",
"Date_To":"12/14/11",
"Date_Type":"range",
"Email_Subject":"[hidden]",
"Email_To":"[hidden]",
"FTP_Dir":"/",
"FTP_Host":"[hidden]",
"FTP_Password":"[hidden]",
"FTP_Port":"21",
"FTP_UserName":"[hidden]",
"File_Name":"test-report",
"Metric_List":[ ],
"Report_Name":"test-report",
"rsid":"[hidden]",

"Date_Granularity":"hour",
}
```

Response:

```
{  
"errors":[
    "Date_Granularity is invalid."
]
}
```

Comment: You may be missing a comma, it looks like there should be one after `rsid` instead of after `Date_Granularity`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a re-formatting issue from when I was hiding values.  Post corrected to match the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, just noticing it now.
Data Warehouse did not support the Hour granularity correctly until Jan 2013 (the error you saw was a symptom of this). Then it was corrected for date ranges less then 14 days. In the July 2013 maintenance release of v15 the 14 day limit should be gone. But I have not verified that myself.

As always the more data you request the longer the DW processing will take. So I recommend keeping ranges to a maximum of a month and uncompressed file sizes to under a 1GB, though I hear 2 GB should now be supported.

If you still have issues please let us know.

Thanks C.

Comment: Cheers, thanks.  If I remember correctly, the error went away when requesting under certain situations, and the production release scenario was fit those criteria.